# How to get XRM context from custom button JavaScript? (online 2013)

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I want to call `Xrm.Utility.openWebResourceDialog(...)` from custom JavaScript that runs when a custom button is pressed.

In order for this to work, I have to have `ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx` loaded. I tried adding the following action to my button's command definition:

```
<JavaScriptFunction FunctionName="isNaN" Library="$webresource:ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" />
```

but when I go to import the solution, I get the following error

> The ribbon item my_command_id is dependent on Web resource
>   id='ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx'

Is there any way to access XRM functionality from custom button JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xrm.Utility.openWebResourceDialog method is not available in the current release and will be added in next release.

Answer (score 0):

In "Library" you must specify your own js web resource where function with "FunctionName" defined, like:

```
<JavaScriptFunction FunctionName="myFun" Library="$webresource:myJsWebResource.js"/>
```

In that function you can use Xrm.Utility.openWebResourceDialog(...), because XRM.Utility functions available in every application page that supports scripting.

[Xrm.Utility Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602956.aspx)

Comment: that's what I have been doing but if i try to call Xrm.Utility.openWebResourceDialog(...) from my custom button JS, it says it is undefined

Comment: I'm just checked up. I dont have CRM 2013, in crm 2011 there is two functions in Utility - openWebResource(..) and openEntityForm(..). It works just fine in ribbon "JavaScriptFunction". Can you alert "Xrm.Utility" and share your result?